# LOGIN PHP MYSQL distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas

Tags: php, html, mysql, regex

estoy teniendo un inconveniente en mi sistema,

tengo una BD MySQL (WAMPP), en la cual tengo configurado triggers para que antes de insertar, lo coloque todo a mayúsculas.

después tengo mi sistema, les dejo la vista, el controlador y el modelo:

vista:

```
<div id="back"></div>

<div class="login-box">

  <div class="login-logo">

    <img src="vistas/img/plantilla/logo-blanco-bloque.png" class="img-responsive" style="padding:30px 100px 0px 100px">

  </div>

  <div class="login-box-body">

    <p class="login-box-msg">Ingresar al sistema de Servicios</p>

    <form method="post">

      <div class="form-group has-feedback">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" name="ingUsuario" required>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>

      </div>

      <div class="form-group has-feedback">

        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" name="ingPassword" required>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>

      </div>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-4">

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Ingresar</button>

        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">

          <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAgregarUsuario" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Registrarse</button>

        </div>

      </div>

      <?php

        $login = new ControladorUsuarios();
        $login -> ctrIngresoUsuario();

      ?>

    </form>
```

controlador:

```
<?php

class ControladorUsuarios{

    /*=============================================
    INGRESO DE USUARIO
    =============================================*/

    static public function ctrIngresoUsuario(){

        if(isset($_POST["ingUsuario"])){

            if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["ingUsuario"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["ingPassword"])){

                $encriptar = crypt($_POST["ingPassword"], '$2a$07$asxx54ahjppf45sd87a5a4dDDGsystemdev$');

                $tabla = "usuarios";

                $item = "usuario";
                $valor = $_POST["ingUsuario"];

                $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::MdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor);

                if($respuesta["usuario"] == $_POST["ingUsuario"] && $respuesta["contrasena"] == $encriptar){



                        $_SESSION["iniciarSesion"] = "ok";
                        $_SESSION["idUsuario"] = $respuesta["idUsuario"];
                        $_SESSION["nombre"] = $respuesta["nombre"];
                        $_SESSION["usuario"] = $respuesta["usuario"];
                        $_SESSION["foto"] = $respuesta["foto"];
                        $_SESSION["apellido"] = $respuesta["apellido"];
                        $_SESSION["correo"] = $respuesta["correo"];

                        echo '<script>

                            window.location = "inicio";

                        </script>';

                }else{

                    echo '<br><div class="alert alert-danger">Error al ingresar, vuelve a intentarlo</div>';

                }

            }else{

                echo '<br><div class="alert alert-danger">No se permiten caracteres especiales.</div>';

            }

        }

    }
```

modelo:

```
<?php

require_once "conexion.php";

class ModeloUsuarios{

    /*=============================================
    MOSTRAR USUARIOS
    =============================================*/

    static public function mdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor){

        if($item != null){

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");

            $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor);

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetch();

        }else{

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll();

        }


        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;

    }
```

El problema es que cuando creo un usuario con minúsculas, él me guarda (por el trigger) en la BD todo con mayúsculas, pero por ejemplo en otro sistema no tenía ese problema, por ejemplo en en la app móvil (Ionic) que ocupa la misma BD. Es más, hago una consulta en el Workbench y me lo trae al usuario haga o no en mayúscula la consulta.

¿Qué puede estar ocasionando ésto? ¿Las expresiones regulares? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?.

Comment: El problema es que tu base de datos no es sensitive case, conviértela, te dejo una pregunta de stack en inglés con el mismo problema
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007450/how-do-you-force-mysql-like-to-be-case-sensitive

Comment: Pero con el framework Ionic hice una app que no hay problema con eso...

Answer (score 1):

Puedes resolver el problema de varias formas, tal vez lo más sencillo es hacer en un query directo a la base de datos:

```
SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE LOWER($item)=LOWER(:$item)
```

De esta forma no importa como hayas guardado los datos en la base de datos. Incluso puedes eliminar el trigger si obtienes los datos de la misma forma:

```
SELECT id, UPPER(user) FROM tabla;
```